# What is the camera that L'Wren Scott is holding in this photo?

Tags: camera-identification

I would like identify the camera that L'Wren Scott is holding in a picture.

This picture was taken between 2006-2013, more probably 2010-2013.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be a [Panasonic DMC-GM1](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/panasonic-lumix-dmc-gm1), in the silver/black with the Lumix G Vario 12-32mm f/3.5-5.6 kit lens. It may also be a mismatched all-black body with the silver lens (typically the black body comes with the black lens). It came out in late 2013, and was succeeded by the GM5.

[image]

This is a micro four-thirds interchangeable lens camera, specifically designed to be as small as possible.